# Vim map pattern not found

Tags: vim

I want to map the F2 button to manage the date in vim.

I'm using vim snippets so I want to be able to write down the date while a certain text is selected, I came up with this:
`vmap <F2> :s/currentdate/\=strftime("%d-%m-%Y")/<CR>`.

It works fine but, here is the problem, I also want to be able to update the time:

`vmap <F2> :s/..-..-....\|currentdate/\=strftime("%d-%m-%Y")/<CR>`.

It doesn't work so I tested it directly on vim, without the F2 mapping and my command (when text is selected):

`:'<,'>s/..-..-....\|currentdate/\=strftime("%d-%m-%Y")/` works fine.

It seems like the map command make the use of the 'OR' (\|) impossible.

Also, if there's another way to update the date, I'd be interested too. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you escape the backslash? vmap <F2> :s/..-..-....\\|currentdate/\=strftime("%d-%m-%Y")/<CR>

Comment: @yolenoyer Wow ! It works ! I really don't get why we need to escape the backslash... cause there's no need to do it while selecting directly in vim. Thanks a lot !

Comment: In a map, "\|" includes a bar "|", but if your :s command is not very magic, you need "\|" outside a map, then "\\|" inside a map. There may be other solutions (i think about <Bslash>), look at :h map_bar, and :h map_backslash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to  @yolenoyer we have the solution (escape the backslash)
`vmap <F2> :s/..-..-....\\|currentdate/\=strftime("%d-%m-%Y")/<CR>`
Don't know why we have to escape it but it works.